Using ChromeOS recovery media error doesn't work as expected
I tried installing ChromeOS using the recovery media extension.
I used a 16gb USB flash drive and when the recovery media finished, multiple windows popped up, my USB flash drive turned into many different partitions for some reason.
When I plug it into my computer to install ChromeOS, I go to the boot manager, select the USB flash drive and nothing happens.
Could someone give me a fix?

Can you give us screenshots and more specific details? We don’t can see what you don’t share with us.

a fix for what?
